# Set filtertoolbar for only one column

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

By default when we add  `jQuery("#tableName").jqGrid('filterToolbar');` it is set for all the columns. How can I restrict `filtertoolbar` option to appear only in one column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [search: false](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acolmodel_options) setting for any column where you don't want that the user search in the column. If you have many columns where you don't want to search and a few column where you want to search, you can change the default value of `search` property to `false` with respect of `cmTemplate: {search: false}` and define explicitly `search: true` property in the columns where you want to permit the searching.